# Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers for “PCI-ID”: 14e4:43ab (rev 06) on Ubuntu touch (Meizu 5Pro)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, aircrack-ng

I am trying to run aircrack-ng on Ubuntu touch (Meizu Pro 5) and I cannot. It seems the issue is with the driver natively used by Ubuntu touch.

Does anyone know how to solve this ?

Comment: I am unaware of any device using the Broadcom STA driver that supports monitor mode. I am also unaware of any alternative driver for your *14e4:43ab* device.  So there is therefore no known solution.